# error: SANE: Error during device I/O (code=9) HPLIP

Tags: scanner, hplip

I am trying to get my HP Officejet 8020 to scan on Kubuntu 20.04, but I keep getting the error:

```
error: SANE: Error during device I/O (code=9)
```

I've ran hp-check and everything seems fine, I've followed the instructions on [HP LaserJet AllInOne, scan does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977202/hp-laserjet-allinone-scan-does-not-work), but to no avail. I've reinstalled HPLIP, both in the discover app and the latest from the HP website. I've installed and re installed the hp-plugin, but nothing seems to work. Here is the output of hp-check:

````
hp-check[50684]: info: :[01mHP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.21.2)[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :[01mDependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
hp-check[50684]: info: :This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
hp-check[50684]: info: :This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
hp-check[50684]: info: :under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :[01mNote: hp-check can be run in three modes:[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the HPLIP supplied tarball
hp-check[50684]: info: :(.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies are installed to successfully compile HPLIP. 
hp-check[50684]: info: :2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro supplied package (.deb,   
hp-check[50684]: info: :.rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball has the proper dependencies installed to         
hp-check[50684]: info: :successfully run.                                                                                      
hp-check[50684]: info: :3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode will check both of the    
hp-check[50684]: info: :above cases (both compile- and run-time dependencies).                                                 
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :Check types:                                                                                           
hp-check[50684]: info: :a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies                                                                 
hp-check[50684]: info: :b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)                           
hp-check[50684]: info: :c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies                                                              
hp-check[50684]: info: :d. [All are run-time checks]                                                                           
hp-check[50684]: info: :PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION                                                                       
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :Status Types:
hp-check[50684]: info: :    OK
hp-check[50684]: info: :    MISSING       - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
hp-check[50684]: info: :    INCOMPAT      - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :---------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| SYSTEM INFO |
hp-check[50684]: info: :---------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: : Kernel: 5.8.0-49-generic #55~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 26 01:01:07 UTC 2021 GNU/Linux
 Host: freedom-IdeaPad-FLEX-14
 Proc: 5.8.0-49-generic #55~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 26 01:01:07 UTC 2021 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 20.04
hp-check[50684]: info: : Bitness: 64 bit

hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :-----------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
hp-check[50684]: info: :-----------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.21.2
hp-check[50684]: info: :HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
hp-check[50684]: info: :HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  20.04 version 
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :[01mCurrent contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.21.2

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.21.2
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.21.2
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.21.2
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes
class-driver=no

hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :[01mCurrent contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :[01mCurrent contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :[upgrade]
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1618410939
pending_upgrade_time = 0

[last_used]
device_uri = escl:http://192.168.1.135:8080

[installation]
date_time = 04/14/21 09:42:56
version = 3.21.2


hp-check[50684]: info: : <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :-------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| External Dependencies |
hp-check[50684]: info: :-------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: : cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.3.1           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
hp-check[50684]: info: : gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.50            OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.29          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.16         OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.20.3          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| General Dependencies |
hp-check[50684]: info: :------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: : libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.3.1           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.3.1           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.31'         OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : libavahi-dev         libavahi-dev                                                 REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.8             OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.5           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3-pyqt5-dbus   PyQt 5 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt5                         OPTIONAL        5.0             5.14.1          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3-pyqt5        PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        5.0             5.14.1          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.16          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.9           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.5           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               7.0.0           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.5.34          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :--------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| COMPILEDEP |
hp-check[50684]: info: :--------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: : libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               9.3.0           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.2.1           OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :---------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| Python Extentions |
hp-check[50684]: info: :---------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: : cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.21.2          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: : hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.21.2          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :----------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| Scan Configuration |
hp-check[50684]: info: :----------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: : hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.21.2          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
hp-check[50684]: info: : scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.21.2          OK         -
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :------------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
hp-check[50684]: info: :------------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :device `hpaio:/net/HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020_series?ip=192.168.1.135' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020_series all-in-one
device `escl:https://192.168.1.135:443' is a ESCL HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series [5D5E17] SSL flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://2600:1700:3545:2180::16:8080' is a ESCL HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series [5D5E17] flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://192.168.1.135:8080' is a ESCL HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series [5D5E17] flatbed scanner
device `hpaio:/net/HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020_series?ip=192.168.1.135' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020_series all-in-one
device `escl:https://192.168.1.135:443' is a ESCL HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series [5D5E17] SSL flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://2600:1700:3545:2180::16:8080' is a ESCL HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series [5D5E17] flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://192.168.1.135:8080' is a ESCL HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 series [5D5E17] flatbed scanner

hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :--------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
hp-check[50684]: info: :--------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :No devices found.
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :---------------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
hp-check[50684]: info: :---------------------------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :[01mHP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :[01m---------------------[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :Type: Printer
hp-check[50684]: info: :Device URI: hp:/net/HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020_series?ip=192.168.1.135
hp-check[50684]: info: :PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020.ppd
hp-check[50684]: info: :PPD Description: HP Officejet Pro 8020 Series, hpcups 3.21.2
hp-check[50684]: info: :Printer status: printer HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020 is idle.  enabled since Wed 14 Apr 2021 08:45:04 AM CDT
hp-check[50684]: info: :Communication status: Good
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :--------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :| PERMISSION |
hp-check[50684]: info: :--------------
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :[32;01mNo errors or warnings.[0m
hp-check[50684]: info: :
hp-check[50684]: info: :Done.```


Does anyone have any ideas?
````

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in Ubuntu 18.04.
I solved it in this way:

- download script at https://developers.hp.com/sites/default/files/hplip-3.22.2-plugin.run (the link points directly to the text file)
- save it
- in a terminal, run the command `sh hplip-3.22.2-plugin.run`.

Finally, I'm able to scan with hp-scan.

Comment: What does the script do and why does this work?

Comment: This installs a proprietary HP plug-in that enables scanning support for many HP machines. Official docs: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binary_plugin.html.